# Minizinc Gecode parse_error(stderr)

Tags: python, constraint-programming, minizinc, gecode

I'm trying to rum my minizinc model through python but it seem to be a problem with the solver Gecode. I've tryed using a simpler model but the result is the same. If i use another solver like chuffed works perfectly.

```
import minizinc 

model = minizinc.Model()

model.add_string("""
var -100..100: x;
int: a; int: b; int: c;
constraint a*(x`*`x) + b`*`x = c;
solve satisfy;
""")
gecode = minizinc.Solver.lookup("gecode")
inst = minizinc.Instance(gecode, model)
inst["a"] = 1
inst["b"] = 4
inst["c"] = 0
result = inst.solve(all_solutions=True)
for i in range(len(result)):
print("x = {}".format(result[i, "x"]))
```

This is a tutorial model i've used for testing and this is the error:

```
result = inst.solve()
File "C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\minizinc\instance.py", line 183, in solve`
return asyncio.run(coroutine)
File`"C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 44, in run
return loop.run_until_complete(main)
File "C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 646, in run_until_complete
return future.result()
File "C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\minizinc\instance.py", line 235, in solve_async`
async for result in self.solutions()
File "C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\minizinc\instance.py", line 450, in solutions
raise parse_error(stderr)
minizinc.error.MiniZincError: MiniZinc stopped with a non-zero exit code, but did not output an error message.
```

Comment: Have you tried running a  MiniZinc instance with Gecode directly from the command line or using the IDE? Is that all working? Maybe using the “verbose” flag can give some additional information if it also doesn’t work there

Comment: The code has back ticks around the two multiplications. What happens if you remove the back ticks, i.e. the constraint is just `constraint a*(x*x) + b*x = c;`?